# android socket application works fine on emulator but crash on android device

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

i got a very unusual problem as my application works fine on emulator in which i'm using java socket programming to connect android device with server pc....but when i install my .apk file in my android mobile it gets crash...it does not connect with my server PC ....
please suggest some solutions why this is happening...i'm posting my socket code here...

```
try {
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("vivek-PC")
                .getHostAddress(), 8888);

        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // textIn.setText("Button Clicked" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

i have tried both way to put hostname as well as my serverIP address bt same result i get/....works fine on emulator and get crashed on device...
please reply soon..

Comment: What is 'crash'? What exception do you get?

Comment: @CodeCaster its not working on my device showing the popup having  error "your app stopped unexpectedly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download android terminal emulator on your device and try to ping your Pc using your pc ip address. if it got success then replace your code`InetAddress.getByName("vivek-PC")
                .getHostAddress()` with the ip address of server PC.
    Hope it will help you..
    if still u face any problem, then plz let me know about it.

Comment: thanx i just follow the same steps as u suggested...n i got succeed..thanx for saving my night.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have the phone connected to your PC through usb...
I think to open a socket you need:
`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET`
have you done that?
A good idea would be to download a terminal emulator and try ping your PC from the phone.
You must also note that the address scope of the emulator is different than the phone.

Comment: Yes.. i have given that permission.
bt still it showing error.